# How to Place the circle and with center in map by giving lat ,lng values, coming from the backend using leaflet map. in angular project

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, leaflet

I have an angular application and have created the map using Leaflet open street map. And my task is to create the circle on map with center,latitude and longitude coming from the Backend API. I have never involved in this Can anyone help me regarding this.

**.component.ts**

```
constructor(private ds:DashboardService,private router: Router) { }
lat: number;
  lng: number;
ngOnInit() {

  var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl:  'assets/leaflet/images/drone.png',
    iconSize: [31,41],
    iconAnchor: [9, 21],
    popupAnchor: [0, -14]
});
 var  map = L.map('map').setView([13.0827, 80.2707], 3);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
 attribution: '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'

    
} ).addTo(map);
```

and service function is
**.service.ts**

```
export class DashboardService {
dta:any;
 url:'http://127.0.0.1:9999'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
 this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(dta=>{

      console.log(dta);
    })
  }
```

I want to place the circle with center and latitude ,longitude that are coming from the backend on the map.